# Browsers doesn't see aliases in /etc/hosts

Tags: networking, dns, browser, hosts

A company I'm working in has a local site, with documentation and etc. where all references are set to "srv-moss" as a domain name, which should be defined in `hosts` file. I added it there but it doesn't seem to work. Even though I can `ping srv-moss` just fine, but attempts to open it in Firefox or Chromium results in `Server DNS said: Server Failure: The name server was unable to process this query`.

What should I do? I tried a bunch of solutions that I found for similar problems, but neither worked for me.

Comment: check `/etc/nsswitch.conf` for the hosts

Comment: In Firefox try the Network monitor (Ctrl+Shift+Q) you might see there what requests are made. If that doesn't help, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Debugging/HTTP_logging for guide how to set up the logging and check the resulting log for DNS requests.

Comment: @Raza I am heard about this file, and I have no idea how it is could help me. I think that probably I have to write an aliases in «hosts» line, but what the syntax? I didn't understood it from a manual, neither I could find an examples on the Internet to the case.

Comment: can you past your `/etc/hosts` file here ?

Comment: @Raza of course, [here it is](http://pastebin.com/1ibubLnS). But as I did said pinging there works fine, so in the «hosts» file surely no an error.

Comment: maybe an .htaccess rule for this site is throwing it off

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are behind a proxy check that Firefox has that configured as well. I am behind a proxy and yes, I had to configure Firefox (when I used it) to connect to certain IPs (or aliases). Just insert the exception for `srv-moss` in the proper Network tab.

If your proxy configured via some kind of a system settings, then there should be an «exceptions» option too. If you're configured a proxy via `/etc/environment` file, so you have to add there a variables `no_proxy="srv-moss"`, `NO_PROXY="srv-moss"`*(to add more than one exception use a comma as a separator)*. Don't forget to re-login in the system, so the `/etc/environment` would be read again.

Comment: Hm. I have a proxy configured via SystemSettings and `/etc/environment`. But I'll try to configure it via FireFox native settings.

Comment: Hm… That's interesting: now in the FireFox an error is `HTTP Error 401.2`. Have no idea why, but I thought that probably in Chromium I could write an exception too — a site main page via IP address in Chromium worked fine. Anyway, I don't understand why both the browsers ignores the `/etc/hosts` file…

Comment: You might want to take a look to the file `/etc/resolv.conf` to check whether there is a DNS server configured or not in that case.

Comment: No, Chromium have no it's own proxy settings ☹ It is call the system ones, and the system probably supposed to work with `/etc/hosts` file as an exceptions. And DNS server configured, because I am talking on SO now ☺ Yes, it is. Btw, as the server resides in LAN, I am tried to disable DNS and restart a NIC, and the browser still doesn't saw it via an alias, although could go there via an IP.

Comment: I have a feelings I am close to solution! As the firefox finally got the site after I added a proxy settings there with an exceptions, so seems that system settings do not cosider aliases in hosts file as an exceptions! And I could ping the site without problem because the ping had never used proxy!

Comment: I found what was wrong, you was the person who pushed me to the answer! I'll edit your answer

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure your system is configure to use host file for the dns by confirming /etc/nsswitch.conf file. It should look like

```
   #hosts:     db files nisplus nis dns
   hosts:      files nis dns
```

You can change the order in which you would like your system to check.

Comment: No, it doesn't worked too ☹