# nslookup, dig, firefox ignoring /etc/hosts file entries

Tags: dns, nsswitch

There is something terribly wrong with my current Debian install. Most programs like firefox, nslookup, dig etc. are ignoring entries in `/etc/hosts` file, actually I use this file for Ad-blocking.

**an example**

a line in `/etc/hosts` file

```
127.0.0.1 www.winaproduct.com
```

when I do `dig +short www.winaproduct.com` it returns the respective IP address of the server, not `127.0.0.1`.

Open `www.winaproduct.com` on firefox, it shows the respective website, but this is not expected.

But there is no problem with `ping`, `busybox nslookup`, `busybox ping`, `resolveip` etc.

So, what is the problem ? And how to fix it ?I think the problem is with the DNS resolving library.

A temporary fix-up, setup `dnsmasq` and change `nameserver` to `127.0.0.1` in `/etc/resolv.conf` .

**update**

problem magically solved after installing `libnss3`, as a dependency of `google-chrome`

default /etc/nsswitch.conf looks like `hosts:    files dns`

how to tell `nslookup`, `dig` etc. ask /etc/hosts file first instead asking directly to the DNS ?

but why `busybox nslookup`, `wget`, `resolveip` etc. are working differently than `nslookup` , `dig` etc. ?

Comment: what does the `hosts:` entry in `/etc/nsswitch.conf` look like?

Comment: @ casey, /etc/nsswitch.conf looks like `hosts:          files dns`

Comment: Please add this key information within your OQ.

Comment: This is clearly not a DNS problem. Please look at this very similar question: http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/158419/31707 .

Answer (score 25):

`nslookup`, `dig`, and `host` are tools for querying DNS name servers.

If your configuration is not provided by a name server (like the information given in `/etc/hosts`) those tools will not show them, because they directly ask the name server.

If you want to check that the "usual" resolution is working (i.e. the way specified in `/etc/nsswitch.conf`) you can use `getent`:

```
getent hosts www.winaproduct.com
```

Comment: `getent hosts www.winaproduct.com` is working perfectly, but `nslookup`, `dig`, `host` etc. are only as example, I want it on **firefox**.

Comment: If it works with getent it should also work with firefox. (Both use the same resoltution mechanism.) If it really does not work check for "unusual" configuration in firefox. Maybe you set some kind of proxy or something like this.

Comment: thanks for the comment, I dont use any unusual firefox configuration, no it is not  working with firefox(38.0.1) .

Comment: I'm very sure it is some browser issue. Try `wget` or some other browser like chrome. If `getent` gives the expected result all of them should.

Comment: awesome, working perfectly with `wget`, so what is wrong with firefox , nslookup , dig etc ? I have tried after `rm -rf .mozilla` , remove any user set configuration, still not working.

Comment: → Arnab: As @michas correctly explained it, there is nothing wrong with `nslookup`, `dig` and `host` because they just ask directly to the DNS. There is something wrong just within your `Firefox`. Check `Preferences > Advanced > Connection Settings...`, you should be on `No proxy`.

Comment: @daniel Azuelos, there is nothing wrong with firefox settings, it's already using `No Proxy`. So how to tell `nslookup`, `dig` etc. ask `/etc/hosts` file first instead asking directly to the DNS ?. Thank you for your valuable comment.

Answer (score 6):

Configure **Unbound** package (installed by default on Linux these days) or install it on Windows. Then your resolver will look to this little lightweight service for all DNS queries. **Unbound** will read in your `/etc/hosts` entries and import them into the resolvers DNS cache.

For everything else, it will proxy your system's DNS queries to your machine's up-stream DNS servers.

Now, all your applications as well as your DNS tools such as `dig`, `host` and `nslookup` can receive answers that originated from your local `/etc/hosts` file.

As an alternative on Linux, you can use **DNSmasq** if you prefer however, when I last looked, it doesn't install on Windows yet.