# How can it be that ssh somename works, while nslookup somename does not?

Tags: ssh, nslookup, host-name-resolution

How to know the IP address of some host `somename` I can `ssh` to? If I do `nslookup` on this host it says "no answer". How can `ssh` resolve it's name then?

---

Neither `/etc/hosts` nor `.ssh/config` explanation worked.

---

### EDIT

Sorry `somename` is fully qualified.

```
ssh somename.somedomain
```

works, while

```
ping somename.somedomain
```

and

```
nslookup somename.somedomain
```

don't

Comment: Is it listed in `/etc/hosts` or `~/.ssh/config`?

Comment: The name could also be resolved using mDNS (Multicast DNS) or LLMNR (Link-Local Multicast Name Resolution).

Comment: It may have an entry in your .ssh/config file

Comment: @StephenKitt neither

Comment: @JohanMyréen how to check?

Comment: Try the command `host somename`.

Comment: @JoshMc The `host` command uses DNS so it is equivalent to `nslookup` in this regard.

Comment: @Dims You could try pinging `somename.local`. `.local` is a special domain reserved for mDNS. For LLMNR you could use [this](https://nmap.org/nsedoc/scripts/llmnr-resolve.html) NMAP script.

Comment: Neardupe https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/212897/nslookup-dig-firefox-ignoring-etc-hosts- and cross https://serverfault.com/questions/303716/linux-command-line-utility-to-resolve-host-names-

Comment: @Stephen Kitt nslookup will find it in hosts.

Comment: @mckenzm no, it won’t.

Comment: @Dims adding successive "didn't work..." statements to the question is unlikely to yield further answers at this stage.  If `getent hosts somename.somedomain` does not resolve the hostname then this is almost certainly something specific to SSH and based on your configuration.  You might have missed Jules's suggestion to test with `ssh somename -v`.  Analysing the output from this is the next step.  With so little information on your question we won't be able to guess.

Comment: @Dims Of course the one file which hasn't been mentioned in all of this is `/etc/ssh/ssh_config`.  This can provide similar options to `~/.ssh.config`.  But if this is the case the output of `ssh -v somename` would make this clearer.

Answer (score 32):

[Nslookup is a program to query Internet domain name servers](https://linux.die.net/man/1/nslookup).  Nslookup is very good for querying DNS servers but it does not give you the whole picture when it comes to name resolution.

On Linux name resolution is most commonly controlled by [NSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_Service_Switch) which is configured by `/etc/nsswitch.conf`.  Specifically, this configuration contains a `hosts` entry.  For example:

```
hosts:          files dns
```

In the above entry you can see that the first thing to be queried is `files` followed by `dns`, meaning that `/etc/hosts` will be queried before DNS.  Other options exist including [LDAP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lightweight_Directory_Access_Protocol), [Multicast DNS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicast_DNS) and [WINS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Internet_Name_Service).

Answering your question directly, SSH resolves the hostname to an IP address using NSS (pulling results from multiple sources) where nslookup only queries the DNS.

You can check to see which IP NSS resolves a hostname to using getent.  For example to resolve `somename`:

```
getent hosts somename
```

---

**Also**  In the case of SSH you can configure host specific information in `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` and `~/.ssh/config`.  This will even let you specify an IP address for a hostname, entirely skipping name resolution.:

The following tells SSH to use `192.168.1.25` for both `dev` and `dev.example.com`.  SSH will use this address *whether or not* these names exist as DNS names for a different IP:

```
# contents of $HOME/.ssh/config
Host dev dev.example.com
    HostName 192.168.1.25
```

Answer (score 10):

> How to know the IP address of some host `somename` I can `ssh` to?

Use the verbose flag (`-v`) of the `ssh` command:

```
ssh somename -v
```

The output should contain, among other things, a line that shows the resolved IP of the server you are connecting to:

```
debug1: Connecting to aur.archlinux.org [5.9.250.164] port 22.
```

---

> If I do nslookup on this host it says "no answer". How can `ssh` resolve it's name then?

The most probable cause of `ssh` being able to resolve a hostname that `nslookup` cannot is that it is configured at the `ssh` level.

Per [the `ssh_config(5)` manual page](https://linux.die.net/man/5/ssh_config), there are three places where `ssh` looks at for config files:

> 1. command-line options
> 2. user's configuration file (~/.ssh/config)
> 3. system-wide configuration file (/etc/ssh/ssh_config)

One of these files may contain your hostname `somename` (or a pattern that matches it) as an alias of another hostname or IP. For example:

```
# explicit alias of somename to 8.8.8.8 IP
Host somename
    HostName 8.8.8.8

# pattern alias (that obviously matches somename) to another hostname
# that is itself resolved via DNS (and that can be nslookup-ed).
Host *
    HostName anotherhostname
```

Please refer to the `ssh_config(5)` manual page explanations of `Host` and `HostName` directives and to the `PATTERNS` section for more information.

Comment: This answer does not answer the question, which was how a host name is recognized, even if it is not server by a DNS server.

Comment: The answer correctly mentions very probable scenario where `ssh user@someserver` seems to "resolve" the `someserver` DNS name (even if this does not actually happen). If the `Host someserver` is configured in `.ssh/config` file, it is then possible to use the ssh command exactly as OP states even if the `someserver` is not in the DNS at all.

Comment: @JohanMyréen The output from `ssh -v somename` includes the IP address (regardless of any `ssh_config` entries). So it directly answers the question "How to know the IP address of some host somename I can ssh to?", as well as being a good first step towards answering "How can it be that ssh somename works...?".

Answer (score 4):

Philip is almost there, but heads off down the `.ssh/config` rathole which it's unlikely you configured.

The commands...

```
getent hosts somename
```

...queries NSS using the `hosts:` lookup line in `/etc/nsswitch.conf`, rather than just DNS as `nslookup` does. It's likely your Unix environment is using more than one naming service; possibly some type of AD integration.

Comment: I wouldn't say I headed off down that route. I added an "also" for completeness.

Comment: @PhilipCouling Sure, but your "pre-also" is incomplete - you're not showing how to arbitrarily resolve a name when the question is about "$thing versus nsloookup".

Comment: As already commented on the Q, `host` is normally part of bind-utils (or equivalent) and like both `nslookup` and `dig` uses only DNS. OTOH `getent hosts` (or possibly `ahosts`) does what you describe.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Incorrect. `host` queries other name services. Agreed that `getent hosts` is the best unambiguous method to query "any configured name services".

Comment: `host` is DNS-only per the man pages and confirmed by testing on the systems I use (CentOS, Ubuntu, FreeBSD, Solaris) as well as [upstream](https://ftp.isc.org/isc/bind9/cur/9.13/doc/arm/man.host.html). Also see the (near)dupes I commented on the Q which also say this.

Comment: @dave_thompson Just my experience, Dave.

Comment: @Rich You must have a different `host` program, not the one that is included in "Bind Tools". `man host` says "NAME   host - DNS lookup utility".

Comment: Well, whaddya know. My apologies. I'm getting this mixed up between the behavior of `host $X` and `ypmatch $X hosts`. If `$X` is in DNS but absent from NIS `hosts`, then `ypmatch` will go fetch a result from DNS.