# How can I terminate ping command after getting the first line of its output?

Tags: streaming

I want to

1. start **ping** command
2. get only the first line
3. after output of the first line terminate ping command and put that first line to a variable

I did :

```bsh
firstline=$(ping -c 1 <site> > tmpfile | head -1)
```

but it completes ping command and then writes to tmp file and then take the first line.
How can I terminate output stream of ping command after output of its first line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you’re trying to use `ping` to resolve host names, and don’t want to wait when the host isn’t pingable (or takes a long time to respond).

`ping` isn’t the best tool for this; instead, you could use `host`, or `dig`, for example, or perhaps most accurately if you want to replicate the lookups performed by `ping`, [`getent hosts`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/212909/86440). These will perform the lookup and return, without trying to contact the host.